# XLSX.utils.book_new() is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, filesaver.js, sheetjs

I am using SheetJS library to convert Excel to JSON and vice versa. While the code to convert Excel to JSON works fine, there are issues with the code to convert JSON  back to Excel. Please find the code below:

```
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
wb.Props = {
    Title: "SheetJS Tutorial",
    Subject: "Test",
    Author: "Red Stapler",
    CreatedDate: new Date(2017, 12, 19)
};

wb.SheetNames.push("Test Sheet");
var ws_data = [['hello', 'world']];
var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);
wb.Sheets["Test Sheet"] = ws;
var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });
function s2ab(s) {

    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
    return buf;

}

saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], { type: "application/octet-stream" }), 'test.xlsx');
```

The above code keeps giving XLSX.utils.book_new() is not a function error. Has anybody come across similar issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting `XLSX.utils.book_new()` from in the first place? Are you following a tutorial? Can you link to the relevant documentation?

Comment: Yes, I am following the tutorial mentioned here:
https://redstapler.co/sheetjs-tutorial-create-xlsx/

Comment: Which script did you include? Because if I try, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/L0dwo9pq/

Comment: @ChrisG, path to the js file does not even exist. It throws 404 file not found error.

Comment: Right, I apparently forgot to save the change. Fixed now.

Comment: I've come across a similar issue but have not been able to figure it out.  I'm getting the following message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'book_new' of undefined`. Were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. It's because the relative path isn't found and therefore cannot call XLSX.utils.book_new. You can use an absolute path to the source code like so:

```
<script lang="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.15.2/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script lang="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```